# Unity HTTP webrequest is very slow on localhost

Tags: unity, unity-networking, http

I'm working on an online game on my computer **localhost**. to do this I use `Xampp`.
Anyway, my problem is that the `UnityWebRequests` between **my game** and **localhost database** are **extremely slow**.

And it doesn't matter how much is big the transferred data between my game and the local database. every `UnityWebRequests` takes one or two seconds of time, or maybe more.
And this problem is completely on my nerve. Because it totally takes a lot of time in every testing and etc.

But when I test it on a **public hosting server** it's perfectly **fine**.
I want to know why this issue happens in local mode? And how can I speed up `Xampp`.

In addition, I tested some other solutions like changing some settings in **Apache** (`httpd.conf`) file and etc but I didn't feel any **improvement on speed**.

And I know it's not about my codes or my unity version because it's very fast when I test it on public host servers.

Operating system: Windows 10
Unity version: 2018.4.36

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Did you try to profile where exactly the bottle neck is? It might be that for example your local database is slow (compared to the hosting one) or that your firewall is inspecting more than it should.

Comment: @Zibelas my firewall is completely turned off.